# Remove UTC from a TIMESTAMP field in SQL(BigQuery)

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp

I have been able to convert a TIMESTAMP field that is in UTC to CST using:

```
SELECT  
    TIMESTAMP(started_at) AS UTC,  
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP (started_at), INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AS CST
```

This returns:

| ROW | UTC | CST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-17 13:07:22 UTC | 2020-05-17 08:07:22 UTC |

The second TIMESTAMP displays the correct date and time but UTC still shows.  What is the simplest way to replace 'UTC' with 'CST' or, alternatively, remove 'UTC' altogether since I don't need the designation in the field itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plain sql replace function inline

```sql
select replace(TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP (started_at), INTERVAL 5 HOUR), 'UTC','') AS CST
```

The above searches the result of your expression (provided in your question) for `'UTC'` and replaces it with nothing `''`.  You could also replace it with `'CST'` as you noted.

Obligatory warning: I believe your query will only be correct half the year as long as DST is observed?  You might want to look into `sys.time_zone_info` and [its reference on the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-time-zone-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you for the assist.  I realize this will only work for the time that the US is in Standard Time but the capstone project case study I am working on is really more focused on the duration of bike rentals and with a nod toward tracking rentals by day of week.  I will however make sure that I note that no conversion to DST was executed and keep it in mind for the next 'real' analysis.:)

Comment: I am now getting this error when I insert the code:  No matching signature for function REPLACE for argument types: TIMESTAMP, STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: REPLACE(STRING, STRING, STRING); REPLACE(BYTES, BYTES, BYTES) at [2:5].  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to convert the timestamp to a `datetime` local value:

```
select datetime(started_at, 'America/Chicago') as started_at_cst
```

Note that the time zone is not stored in the data value.  Instead, this encodes the value in the string.

If you want to include the time zone value, I have found that the best approach is to use a string (argghh!).  The following constructs a string:

```
 format_timestamp('%F %X%z', started_at, 'America/Chicago') as started_at_str
```

which can be converted easily into a timestamp for date/time calculations:

```
timestamp(started_at_str)
```

Comment: Ok.  No need to include timezone value for this one.  I just want to be able to calculate the correct day of the week in the correct time zone and not have the distraction of showing the wrong time zone label even though the TIMESTAMP was updated. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: @KevinKish . . . There is no "wrong" timezone for `TIMETSTAMP`s.  They are always represented in UTC.  If you store the value as strings, then you can get around this problem.

Comment: Ahh. So that probably explains why I couldn't find the solution where I was searching for it ... by trying to convert the TIMESTAMP itself.  Really good to know now.  Gotta go put some ice on my head where I was banging it against the desk ;)

Comment: @KevinKish . . . I described the solution that I came up with.